# Как правильно осуществить множество разных запросов QNetwork

Tags: qt, qnetworkrequest

Пишу небольшео ПО которое поятоянно работает с `api`. Для запросов использую `QNetworkAccessManager` и у него есть сигнал `finished` к которому я подключил свой слот. Сам `connect` указываю в кострукторе класа. Я правильно понмаю, что как только я буду делать запрост через `QNetworkAccessmanager` то будет вызыватся слот который указан в `connect`. Но вот задача, запросов будет много, соответственно мне надо и много слотов для обработки данных. Почитал что есть у `QNetworkReply` сигнал `QIODevice::readyRead` который будет вызыватся после того как данные будут получены для чтения. `connect` я укажу в функции которая будет отправлять запрос. Но вот немогу понять как читать из него данные. Или как правильно арганизовать множество `POST/GET` запросов в одном классе.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Когда Вы делаете запрос, Вы можете подцепить к Вашему запросу свои пользовательские данные (например, номер запроса), что бы потом по получению ответа суметь идентифицировать причину отсылки этого запроса.

Сами данные можно подцепить с помощью "динамических свойств функцией [setProperty](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#setProperty) сразу после выполнения `QReplay::get` (тут немного странно звучит, но если знать, что если позвать `QReplay::get`, то запрос на самом деле не будет отправлен, пока EventLoop не получит управление, а это произойдет обычно по выходу с функции. И это позволяет после вызова get/post навесить обработчики и все такое).

В слоте finished  с помощью `property("имя-свойства").isNull()` проверяете, если у пришедшего ответа Ваши данные (эти данные не передаются в внешний мир, они живут внутри объекта `replay`). и если ок, то как то так `reply->property().toString("имя-свойства");` получаете, что там.

Ещё раз. с помощью get/post отправляете запросы, добавив им своих пользовательских данных для идентификации. а в слоте finish просто проверяете и отправляете в нужное место на обработку.

код с примером можно найти в похожем вопросе https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40707025/how-to-make-qnetworkreply-to-return-custom-data

Ещё один способ заключается в том, что бы завести мапу (`QMap`), которая будет хранить как ключ указатель на `replay`, а значением некую структуру с пользовательскими данными. Суть та же, но эту структуру нужно будет сделать доступной в двух местах, что не очень хорошо.

Третий способ состоит в том, что `QReplay` имеет свой собственный [finished](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qnetworkreply.html#finished),  а значит при отправке запроса можно тут же подписаться на нужный обработчик. В комбинации с первым способом может быть вполне хорошим решением.

`QIODevice::readyRead` интересная идея, но в ней есть один минус - сокет имеет полное право прислать ответ не одним куском, а несколькими. И Вам придется решать ту же задачу, которую за Вас уже решил `QNetworkManager`...

Comment: Спасибо большое за указание пути) Последний впрос, правильно ли я понял, что после того как я указал `setProperty` некий индификатор, то потом приполучении просто проверяю его типо `case`? И получается один слот на получение любых даных и внем что-то подобие `case` по индификатору выбираю реализацию полученых данных

Comment: да, там можно сделать. Все зависит только от Вашей конкретной задачи

Comment: только уменя заработало все так
`if (!reply->property("name").isNull())` 
то есть если значение `name` не пустое, так как `Null` означает что-то типо пустоты, то я получаю данные `name`. Наверное правильно будет поправить вашу статью. Может в будущем комуто-то пригодится, а народ редко читает дальше ответа))

Comment: логично, что так заработало:)